# Maintain picture position when screen rotated

Tags: android, android-camera

How to maintain a picture position when screen rotated. With this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import android.hardware.Camera.Face;
import android.hardware.Camera.FaceDetectionListener;

public class PreviewActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback {

   Camera mCamera;
   SurfaceView surfaceView;
   Button prompt;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
      surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
      surfaceView.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      Toast.makeText(this, "onPause!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
     Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   public void onCancelClick(View v) {
      finish();
   }

   public void onSnapClick(View v) {
      mCamera.takePicture(this, null, null, this); // Invoke onShutter()
   }

   @Override
   public void onShutter() {
      Toast.makeText(this, "onShutter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "onPictureTaken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      if (data != null) {
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

         if (bitmap != null) {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dirr");
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
               file.mkdir();
            }

            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dirr", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");


            try {
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);

               fileOutputStream.flush();
               fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
               exception.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
         camera.startPreview();//restart

      }
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

      Toast.makeText(this, "surfaceChanged!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
      List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
      Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);

      params.setPreviewSize(selected.width, selected.height);
      //Toast.makeText(this, "size!" + String.valueOf(selected.width + "," + selected.height), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mCamera.setParameters(params);

      mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

      mCamera.startPreview();

   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "surfaceCreated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mCamera = Camera.open();
      try {

         mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {


      if (mCamera != null) {
         mCamera.stopPreview();
         mCamera.release();
         mCamera = null;
      }
      Toast.makeText(this, "surfaceDestroyed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.i("PREVIEW", "surfaceDestroyed");
   }
}
```

**Vertically**, it produces:

[image]

**Horizontally**, it produces:

[image]

**What I want to achieve**:

[image]

I think because this  *`mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);`* keep restarted when the screen is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check what orientation the device is in, whether it is LANDSCAPE or PORTRAIT and set mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(angle) based on that. You can do this with something like this:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(angle1);
else mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(angle2);
```

Comment: Hi thanks I'll try it tomorrow and let you know .I'm home now thanks :)